# Как сделать вывод имя пользователя на странице "Спасибо"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, вёрстка

В корне сайта на одном уровне находится главная страница: *index.html*, страница благодарности после отправки формы:*thank-you-page.html*, обработчик формы: *success.php*, в папке js находится главный *main.js* и *jquery*.

После успешной отправки формы пользователь попадает на страницу благодарности, в форме он заполняет два поля — имя и телефон. Вопрос, как на странице благодарности сделать вывод имя пользователя? Чтобы было, например, так: "Спасибо, [Имя] за заявку!"

Код для формы в *main.js* предоставил ниже. На странице, форм несколько, они идентичные, обработчик используется один. И нужно, чтобы имя бралось с той формы, с которой идет отправка заявки.

Это код для формы:

```
// form submission
$('[data-submit]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
})
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function(value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    },
    "Пожалуйста, проверьте свои данные"
);
function valEl(el){

    el.validate({
        rules:{
            name:{
                required:true
            },
            phone:{
                required:true,
                regex: '^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$'
            }
        },
        messages:{
            name:{
                required:'Поле обязательно для заполнения'
            },
            phone:{
                required:'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                regex:'Телефон может содержать символы + - ()'
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('.loader').fadeIn();
            var $form = $(form);
            var $formId = $(form).attr('data-id');
            switch($formId){
                case'goToNewPage':
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: $form.serialize(),
                    })
                        .always(function (response) {
                            setTimeout(function (){
                                $('.loader').fadeOut();
                            },800);

                            //ссылка на страницу "спасибо" - редирект

                            location.href='http://test.com/thank-you-page.html';
                        });
                    break;
                case'popupResult':
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: $form.attr('action'),
                        data: $form.serialize(),
                    })
                        .always(function (response) {
                            setTimeout(function (){
                                $('.loader').fadeOut();
                                $('.modal').fadeOut();
                                $('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut();
                            },800);
                            setTimeout(function (){
                                $('.thank-you-page').fadeIn();
                            },1100);
                            $('.thank-you-page').on('click', function(e) {
                                $(this).fadeOut();
                                $('.modal-open').css({
                                    'overflow': 'inherit',
                                    'padding-right' : '0'
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
}

$('.js-form').each(function() {
    valEl($(this));
});
$('[data-scroll]').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'data-scroll') ).offset().top
    }, 2000);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно в url страницы спасибо передавать закодированное имя как параметр, а на этой странице написать скрипт для раскодирования имени и заполнения поля.

location.href='http://test.com/thank-you-page.html#'+encodeURIComponent(name);

Comment: на странице благодарности можно будет получить имя через location.hash